# Need help on a regexp to do multiple replacements

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am in need of a regexp to strip three letters (ACC) and add a preceding 0 based on the input having 00X in a single expression.

```
Input            Output
ACC00977810916   000977810916
ACC000977220916  000977220916 
ACC001077330916  001077330916
```

Have been trying with capture groups but have not been able to get what I need.   Using Microsoft vbscript 5.5.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What was it you tried with a capturing group?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The number of `0` depends on the length of the rest of the string.

Comment: What language are you using? Most languages have a way to add padding to make a string a desired length. This isn't something appropriate for a regexp because they can't generate a variable size replacement.

Comment: Wiktor, I am forced to use regex, I can't just replace ACC with a 0 as it makes the other cases fail.  Thank you for the input.

Comment: Capture group isn't useful for this, you're trying to add something, not copy from the original.

Comment: First, what is the regex flavor? Second, is there *always* a `0` after `ACC`? There are tens of regex libraries out there.

Comment: Regexp is from Microsoft, vbscript v5.5 in a scanning program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to decide whether or not to add `0` based on the length of the string and you have to use regex, you may try something like this:

```
^ACC0?(?=\d{11}$)
```

..and replace with `0`.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XXF3K2/1/)**.

A solution without Lookahead:

```
^ACC0?(\d{11})$
```

..and replace with `0$1`.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TgaLlx/2/)**.

Answer (score -1):

Do separate replacements for each possible length of the input:

```
^ACC(\d{10})$ => 00$1
^ACC(\d{11})$ => 0$1
^ACC(\d{12})$ => $1
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to do it in one single expression. :(

Comment: Regular expressions aren't a magical tool that can do all replacements.